# Would it be possible to follow tutorials that use vue-cli but with CLI 3?

Tags: vue.js

I have just started learning Vue.js. The author is using `npm install -g vue-cli` but it did not work with me because I got stuck with technical issues and I tried many solutions to fix it but I couldn't. 
**So I want to follow up with the author but using `npm install -g @vue/cli`. So Do you think I it will be easy to follow up with him? I mean are these different versions use different syntax?**

Comment: Have you looked on google for alternatives

Comment: [Vue CLI 3](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/) is the last version and what is usually refered to as vue-cli, so what is your question?

Comment: I updated my question to make it more understandable. -- @Sumurai8

Answer (score 0):

The `vue-cli` package seems to be the old cli. The main difference between this version and Vue CLI 3 is that the webpack configuration used to be visible in the project as a `build` directory. To make changes to the build process you used to have to modify files within this folder. In Vue CLI 3 this has been moved to a helper that consumes a configuration file `vue.config.js` in the project. The structure of files has been slightly altered in this version of the CLI. Both work with Vue 2.x, so the way you write .vue files has not changed in any way.

Overall you should have little trouble following the tutorial, unless you are going to make changes to the build process. In that case, simply consult the official documentation or find a tutorial that is specifically for Vue CLI 3.